# wait_for timeout to over come asyncio.queue not having a timeout not working

Tags: python-asyncio

I was trying to run the following code. The code is an example for adding item to queue from another thread, and having an exception when timeout happens if the queue is not supplied with new items.

```
import asyncio
import threading
import time


async def responder(queue, value):
    value["value"] = await queue.get()


async def worker(queue):
    value = dict()
    while True:
        print("waiting")
        # new_msg = await queue.get()
        asyncio.wait_for(responder(queue, value), timeout=2)
        print(value)
        print("worked")


class wManager():
    def __init__(self):

        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)

        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()

        self.loop.create_task(worker(self.queue))

        self.msg = 0

    def add(self):
        print("queue Size Before"+str(self.queue.qsize()))
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.queue.put(self.msg), self.loop)

        self.msg += 1
        print("queue Size After"+str(self.queue.qsize()))

    def start(self):
        self.loop.run_forever()


def print_after_sleep(manager):

    while True:
        print("hi!")
        time.sleep(3)
        manager.add()


def manager_runer(manager):
    manager.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = wManager()
    manager_thread = threading.Thread(target=manager_runer, args=(manager,), daemon=True)

    sleepy_thread = threading.Thread(
        target=print_after_sleep, args=(manager,), daemon=True)

    sleepy_thread.start()
    manager_thread.start()
    sleepy_thread.join()
```

I want to be able to have a timeout if the queue is not getting new items after a period of predetemined time. 
The problem is that `responder()` is not awaited.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use an asyncio.Queue to send data between threads.  From the docs: "Although asyncio queues are not thread-safe, they are designed to be used specifically in async/await code."

Comment: @PaulCornelius That was my first reaction as well, but the OP is actually using cross-threads asyncio correctly, if unnecessarily. Note in particular the use of `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()` when enqueuing across threads.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `await` in front of `asyncio.wait_for()`. You also probably want to add a try/catch to handle the `TimeoutError` raised by the call in case of timeout.